# Alt+Tab to Desktop in XP like in Vista/7

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, alt-tab

Is there *any* way to add the empty desktop entry to the task switch list to switch to it with alt+tab in windows xp? Like in windows 7.

I know this is not (or at least not public/documented) part of Windows XP so I'm looking for workarounds (like [ahk](http://www.autohotkey.com/)), enhancments/extensions, hooks, wrappers/emulators, hacks (like dll hacks or alternate dll versions from other ms products) or as last resort replacements.

Comment: This might not help you much, but win+d is a lot faster than alt tabbing around.

Comment: @SBI thanks! but my problem with `win+d` since 95 is that it is too easy to destroy the original window "inter-layout" with it. if you use alt+tab after win+d, then the old layout is lost and you have to restore the windows manually, one-by-one. *Ideally*, I would like the desktop be just another window when task-switching, but below everything (so desktop effects work and no funny always-on-top behaviour with fake desktops)

Comment: @naxa Its not possible to add this feature to Windows XP.

Comment: @naxa: Try the app I suggested on your other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Desktop!](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#Desktop) by Skrommel, a freeware program which gives the desktop window (because that's what the desktop is, a maximized always-on-bottom folder window) its own taskbar button. Which can then of course be Alt-Tab'ed to.

Comment: thank you sir! it's even **open source**, they are AHK scripts. what's more, **this coder's page is a gold mine**!
has 50+ great fun program

Comment: may I ask how did you find out that the desktop is a window? (any more revealing resource on this matter?)

Comment: I used to mess around with installing software like this a lot, also messed with alternative shells, that's where my information about the desktop window came from...just picked it up experiences. I'm not a programmer so I apologize that I cannot give a more precise answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could minimize all open windows (but not dialogs) with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and later restore the windows with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

You could also show the desktop with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and later restore the windows with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

If you want to keep the window order when restoring you should try to not to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> after showing the desktop with keys like above.

Comment: +1 this actually works! I will wait a little in case someone comes up with an alt-tab solution. I actually recall I once knew this so alt+tab would have the advantage for me that I can remember it more easily, apparently. :)

Comment: -1 this actually doesn’t work. This minimises only minimisable windows (not including dialogs), while Win-D also brings the desktop to front.

Comment: @kinokijuf It works, but not in all cases :). I edited my answer to give win+m and win+d and tell the difference.

Comment: it seems that `win`+`shift`+`m` actually restores the layout *even after* `win`+`d` - latter minimizes dialogs, too. although if I do *any* task switch the dialog and its parent window comes up without me asking.

Comment: @Weerner WinD doesn’t minimise the dialogs, for they can’t be minimised. It minimises windows _and_ brings the desktop to front, effectively hiding dialogs behind it.